# If the universe is infinite, would it be homogenous?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, symmetry, universe

I know, that we can't really know the answer to that, but what is the current state of understanding?

We seem to assume that on very large scales, the universe is homogenous. As I understand it, this means that if we put a large enough radius "blur filter", averaging out everything in the region, everything would look the same (consensus seems to be in the range of a few 100 Mpc).

- Now if the universe is infinite, would this still hold?
- If not: what would be different and why?

Comment: Simple question: Why should it be? And if it isn't, what does it matter?

Comment: I think the relative uniformity of the CMB in all directions suggests that the universe is about the same in all directions to the point of the edge of the observable universe. So if the universe at larger scales isn't homogenous, why does is seem homogenous in our corner of the universe?

Comment: The CMB comes from matter that was quite close to "us" 300,000 years after the big bang. It can't tell us anything about things that happened farther away. See e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/478674/how-far-was-the-surface-of-last-scattering-at-the-moment-of-recombination#:~:text=If%20I%20understand%20correctly%2C%20then,just%20before%20the%20particle%20horizon.

Comment: I am wondering, is there some Penrose argument that could be made that a infinite universe had to be uniform at some large enough scale? Of course that scale would in general be larger than the horizon and so that would be cosmologically irrelevant, but does such a mathematical argument exist? I'm thinking that one might add in that density fluctuations can only be finite, thus homogeneity might have to be realized at large enough scales.

Comment: @rfl I don't think there is any such argument by Penrose. Even the conformal treatment of infinity is by definition scale independent. However, there are articles on back-reaction in cosmology, where we interpret that our universe to be inhomogeneous, but the averaged dynamics on cosmological scale can mimic Friedmann equations

Comment: If you are willing to assume that what we see is representative of what is beyond, you can make some interesting conclusions. The observable universe has been measured to be pretty near flat. The minimum radius of curvature is $> 42$ Gpc. This could imply that the minimum volume of the universe is $250$ times the observable volume.  [Applications of Bayesian model averaging to the curvature and size of the Universe](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/227699444_Applications_of_Bayesian_model_averaging_to_the_curvature_and_size_of_the_Universe)

Answer (score 5):

> If the universe is infinite, would it be homogenous ?

As far as we can tell, the observable universe is homogenous at scales of 100Mpc or greater. However, this is an empirical observation. There is no theoretical reason why the universe *must* be homogenous at large scales, and no theoretical reason why this homogeneity *must* extend beyond the observable universe. So the answer is "we don't know".

Comment: So if we first need to know why the observable universe seems monotonous above a scale of 100Mpc to make any useful prdictions about the stuff outside the observable universe?

Comment: Some not totally stupid people are actually questioning even the100Mpc  homogeneity assumption based on the available data, if I am not mistaken, so even the local universe may turn out to be a little more grainy than we had hope for if these folks are right.

Comment: @kruemi As I said [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/31795/16685) "We assume that the observable universe is typical of the whole universe, but of course that's impossible to verify". Occam's Razor suggests that we might as well assume that the whole universe *is* homogeneous, since we can't make any measurements that would indicate otherwise, and a theory that predicts large-scale inhomogeneity is more complicated than a theory that predicts homogeneity.